# How to insert/remove items from RecyclerView using MVP

Tags: android, architecture, android-recyclerview, mvp

While using recycler view in MVP, where do you guys keep a reference to the list? I have a `ChatManager` which can talk to different presenters. I keep two copies of the list  of messages , one in the `ChatManager` and the other in the `Presenter`. The adapter, view, and the presenter share the same list.
The reason I have a reference to the list of messages in the `Presenter` is because I have some business logic for removal and scrolling which I want to handle from the presenter.

So now when I have to remove a message, the presenter decides what item to remove and removes it from the list. Now it needs to let the view know that a message has been removed. So in that case, should it say `view.remove(message)` or `view.remove(index)`? The view should not try and remove the message again since the presenter has already done that.

Same thing for other operations like scrolling or adding. If new messages are received, the presenter adds the `newMessages` to `allMessages` and then has to update the view. Ideally, the presenter should be calling `view.onMessagesReceived(List<Message> messages)` instead of `view.onMessageReceived(int newMessagesCount, int indexAddedAt)`. The second method is really weird and not verbose at all. But since the list is being shared, the view only needs to call `notifyItemInserted` and hence only needs to know about the count and the index.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: I did like that: I store list of data in presenter,  no need to copy to view. When something changes in presenter (from model), I can call `view.changeData()`, and your activity/fragment can access to data by `presenter.getData()`. An Action do with view has a relevant method to presenter (add new message, load more .... )

Comment: @akshayt23 first time set data list view.onMessagesReceived(List<Message> messages) after any changes affected like (Add,Edit,Remove)  options flow like  notifyItemInserted(int lastPostion) Edit NotifyItemChanged(int position) get position from messages by unique id delete also same

Answer (score 2):

So as Amir suggested, one way to go about it is expose a method from the adapter to update the data, and call `notifyDataSetChanged`. I really didn't want to use this method as it unnecessarily refreshes the entire data set when I only wanted to add/update messages in the adapter.

Another way was to expose a method `addNewMessages(int count, int index)` in the view, so that the adapter knows which indices to notify insert/update for, which I again didn't want to use because then the API seems weird as `addNewMessages` should actually be passed the list of new messages instead of the index and count.

The solution I went with was to actually pass the entire updated list from the `Presenter` to the `View`, which eventually passes it to the `Adapter`. The `Adapter` then uses `DiffUtil` to figure out the diff between the old list and the new list and calls only the `notifyItemInserted`/`notifyItemChanged` methods instead of `notifyDataSetChanged` every time.

This helps because now the API looks like this:

```
ChatPresenter {
    interface View {
    ...
    void updateMessages(List<Message> messages);
}

Activity implements ChatPresenter.View {
    ...
    @Override
    void updateMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        chatsAdapter.update(messages);
    }
}

ChatsAdapter {
    ...
    public update(List<Message> messages) {
        DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new ChatMessageDiffCallback(this.messages, updatedMessages));

        this.messages = updatedMessages;
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best practice is to update adapter list from the view implementation but the function for this task should be on view interface and implemented in view implementation (e.g. fragment or activity)

firstly add a method to your adapter like below

```
public void updateItemsList(ItemsList itemsList)
{
   //update the list of your items assume your items list is named "mItemsList"
   this.mItemsList = itemsList;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

then in your view interface add a method to update the adapter list like below

```
public void updateAdapterList(ItemsList itemsList);
```

then in your view implementation (fragment or activity) add this:

```
@Override
public void updateAdapterList(ItemsList itemsList);
{
   //update the adapter list -- assume your adapter is named "mAdapter"
   mAdapter.updateItemsList(itemsList);
}
```

now you can access this method (updateAdapterList()) wherever you have an object of type view interface.